# PHP scraping dynamically loaded content

Tags: php, web-scraping, dynamic-content

I am trying to scrape a website for article titles, however this page only loads the five first titles and loads more when the user scrolls down the page (JSON calls more articles and injects into the page).

The web scraper that I built works perfectly, but only finds the first 5 default articles, and what I am trying to achieve is to load more than 5. Is there any way of achieving that using PHP and if you can explain me why/how it works I would really appreciate because I love to learn these things.

Comment: You will need to post your code, without it how do you think anyone would be able to give you an answer?

Comment: instead of scrapping the page you could try and directly access the source, injecting any POST/GET required parameters with curl

Comment: Lawrences suggestion is the most plausible but not knowing the site in question makes answering difficult.

Have you also checked to see if the site has an rss feed for example or a site map?

Comment: Bear in mind that your scraper may break if the target site(s) in question change their HTML structure or their UI approach.

Comment: There are no feeds/apis present in the website, if there were this would be so much easier.

Comment: @halfer yes I am aware of that and the code is built in a way that will warn me to update the script once the code changes, so that is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use chrome's network monitor to log the source of the ajax requests and then request those from your webscraper, but this really is a "make shift api" , and will brake if the site changes it's json format, you can use the php function json_decode to decode the json.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

in order to first retrieve the data, you will have to use file_get_contents

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

but this will only allow GET
If you want more "advanced" options ( like POST ) you will have to look into cURL

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: So you are suggesting to mimic the calls made in the article website in order to return the next results?

Comment: That is indeed what i am suggesting, but it's tricky business because there isn't really any data contract. It might be better to look for a usable rss feed or api, but i guess that isn't the idea behind your webscraper.

Comment: Yes, I can see how that would work better but as of now there are no feeds/apis that can be used for this purpose. So using json-decode would allow me to interact with the scrolldown calls that occur in the webpage or that part had to be executed and then php would decode the results?

Comment: Alright, thank you for your attention, your answer will be marked as accepted for now since yours gave me a better insight on this method.

Comment: @user524695 json_decode function will allow you to decode a json string returned from the source into a workable array or object. what your seeing on the site in question is js or jquery interacting with a self api. if you can mimic the parameters passed from the js to the api then you can decode the result with json_decode, but without a link to the site we cannot give a full answer and only suggestions ;0

Comment: @helmus file_get_contents can also POST if you use stream_context_create ;)

Comment: @Lawerence I understand that but if I wanted to provide the link I would have done it in the question. I may search for a similar behaviour webpage to show as an example.

Comment: Good answer. @user524695 - in some cases you need to examine what is sent in the header of the JSON request, since some servers won't treat a request as JSON unless it is present. As helmus says, use the AJAX monitor in your browser to check this.

Comment: "if I wanted to provide the link I would have done it in the question" - that is rarely the case here. We frequently see incomplete questions, so users with good rep can be forgiven for asking for further info! `:-)`

Comment: @halfer I was not aware of that, I apologize for my mistake.
Regarding the website in question, the reviewer said he adopted a behaviour from a service called sky drive and changed the max results from 100 to 5, however I am not familiar with this service but will try to find an example since he uses the same system as theirs.

Comment: @user524695 - no problem at all.